# Why 'Makefile' demands dependency?

Tags: make

I wonder why 'Makefile' demands dependency line in spite of a command line already has list of file.
For example,

> hello : main.o hello.o
>
> ```
>         gcc -o main.o hello.o
> ```

The gcc command already contains main.o, hello.o. Writing dependency line looks inefficient.

Comment: I'm feeling you may have missed the point of `make` somewhat: it's primary advantage isn't just to blindly run a set of commands (shell scripts are perfectly good at that), but to work out which commands need to be run. It can't do that without dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it's the build rule that is unnecessary, not the dependency. It the dependencies that makes `make` tick, after all. The rule for building is also seriously wrong (will overwrite `main.o` rather than building `hello`).

Using the implicit rules, this may be shortened to just

```
hello: main.o hello.o
```

Or if you want an explicit make rule in addition to the dependency:

```
hello: main.o hello.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```